# Different appearance on each major browser

Tags: html, css, hover

**Update** I implemented the CSS Reset and to no avail. The answer by Kejko also did not help and instead made it worse. (Chrome now displays it incorrect with the change in styles)

This may be the problem since I know actual tables can not be positioned relative?

```
.chatIcons {
    display: table;
}
```

**End Update**

I was about to have my site go live after I tested how each page looked on the major browsers and ran into a problem. The problem seems to be involved with the hover effect of the icons.

**In chrome** the icon section appears exactly how I want it to.

**In FireFox** it appears the same but once one it is hovered it only effects the third icon and the `.iconInfo`'s overlay from staying relative to the parent, instead it is doing 100% width and height of the main parent container.

**In IE 10-11** it keeps everything correct but once it is hovered the "overlay" is not 100% height anymore and the height actually varies.

Here is the css pertaining to the hover:

```
.iconInfo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
}

.icon:hover .iconInfo {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I have included a fiddle to help, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/scLTD/1/)

Comment: Just for the record, do you use something like css reset oder normalize.css?

Comment: @Johnny000 I do not, do you think it is some default styles causing this?

Comment: The IE bugs sounds to me like something that could be related to default styles ..

Comment: I will give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: I just tried out the css reset and it did not fix anything pertaining to the problem, any ideas?

Comment: I'm at home now and testing, what's sure, it's caused by the image resize.

Comment: Thank you for spending the time to help me, hopefully it is something that can be fixed!

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

.icon {
    border-radius: 5px;
    **display: inline-block;**
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    **width: 32.99%;**
}

That should fix your problem.

Comment: Did you test this? because it does not work and even makes chrome display it wrong now.